# I am looking for robot constructor general plastic parts

Tags: plastics

I do not know how call it, but I mean something like these pics:

[image]

[image]

Can I find something like this plastic parts in general or I must design them in solidworks and ordering for mold production by myself?

My goal is to build some educational robot kits for kids by this parts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not relate to LEGO or LEGO compatible products.

Comment: Appears to been re-asked as [Which LEGO set is best suited to build robots?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9229/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first picture is from [Elector](http://www.elector.ir/learn1.htm), 
 the second is [kai robot](http://www.pishrobot.com/eng/product-en/kai/).

They are both robotic kits from Iran, you can order kits from their site.

If you are looking for a Lego solution,
the [Lego Eduction](https://education.lego.com/en-us) program has robotic kits like  [Mindstorm](https://education.lego.com/en-us/middle-school/shop/mindstorms-ev3) and [WeDo](https://education.lego.com/en-us/elementary/shop/wedo-2), or you could look at Lego [Boost](https://www.lego.com/en-us/boost/)

Comment: Thank you Syberion, which one is good to build kid size soccer robot (3 wheel) and robot warrior contest?